# How to stop Excel VBA from renaming variables and parameters in unrelated modules and methods?

Tags: excel, vba

I noticed unbelievable destructive behavior of Excel VBA. It silently and automatically renames variables and function parameters in unrelated modules when I add, say, a new property to class. Observed on Office Professional Plus 2016 and Windows 10.

For concrete example, I have one module and one class. Module looks like this:

```
Private Function MyRequests() As Collection
    Dim requests As Collection
    Set requests = New Collection
    Dim row As Integer
    row = 3
    Dim oRequest As New MyRequest
    oRequest.Name = "SomeName"
    requests.Add oRequest
    MyRequests = requests
End Function
```

Class `MyRequest` looks like this:

```
Private sName As String

Property Let Name(sValue As String)
    sName = sValue
End Property
```

Now the unbelievable part comes. I add new property to the `MyRequest` class:

```
Private iRow As Integer

Property Let Row(iValue As Integer)
    iRow = iValue
End Property
```

I save code, go to module and its private function which now looks like this:

```
Private Function MyRequests() As Collection
    Dim requests As Collection
    Set requests = New Collection
    Dim Row As Integer
    Row = 3
    Dim oRequest As New MyRequest
    oRequest.Name = "SomeName"
    requests.Add oRequest
    MyRequests = requests
End Function
```

**Notice that `row` became `Row`**! This silent auto-renaming also happens throughout the VBA code in sheets... Basically everywhere, Excel renamed `row` to `Row`!

So, my question is what can I do to stop this insane behaviour?

Comment: You cannot use `Row` as variable! `Row` is reserved by Excel VBA and used like `Range.Row` property. Try `rW` or something else instead...

Comment: @FaneDuru Well, I didn't. I used `row`. Excel changed it automatically to `Row`.

Comment: I just explained to you why Excel does that to "your" variable. Did you try changing your `row` variable in `rW` to see if Excel is upset on you or on the way you named the variable...?

Comment: @FaneDuru Crazy! Do you maybe know of a list of such reserved variable names? I guess that row/Row is not the only one.

Comment: You wrongly guessed! Excel VBA variables are NOT case sensitive...

Comment: So I was super unlucky and stumbled upon the only one reserved variable in whole VBA - `Row`???

Comment: Who said it is the "only one"...?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I found a list of all Visual Basic reserved words which shouldn't be used as names for variables or procedures: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/keywords/

Comment: Practically, `row, rows, column, columns, range` etc. can be used as variables! But it is recommended to not use them like variables name. Excel VBA can be confused in some circumstances. And in your case, you maybe created another variable named `Row` and VBA remembered that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem isn't arising because you're using variable names that match a built-in property. It's arising simply because you're using two different case-spellings of the same variable. If you used `iRow` in one module and `irow` in another, you would still get the same issue.

You can't stop this behaviour. The VBA IDE automatically changes the names of subroutines, functions, variables and properties to match the case of the last declaration statement that was edited. It also then remembers the case used for all future instances entered/edited anywhere in code.

When doing this renaming, the IDE doesn't distinguish between local and global variables, or properties of different classes. If you change the case anywhere, it will be updated and used everywhere.

This is actually useful to help prevent accidental code errors. VBA is case-insensitive and using different case would not create different variables. Trying to manage different variables based on case, even in different modules, is not good practice.

If they are local and distinct with no risk of confusion, then you might as well use the same case-spelling anyway. Why have one naming convention in one module and a different naming convention in a different module?

However, if you need to distinguish between variables in different modules, then you should be using different character-spelling anyway and in doing so, the issue would not arise.

This behaviour also helps you to ensure code is being correctly entered as you type, especially if you declare all variables, subroutines etc with at least one capital letter. You are then able to edit all code using only lower case, which reduces effort, and then everything that is correctly spelled will be automatically converted to the declared case. If you type a variable in lower case and it does not automatically change case, then you know immediately that you have mistyped the variable, rather than discovering the error only when you try to compile/run.

Note that the issue that *does* arise from using built-in properties as names for variables and subroutines is that the automatic changing of case applies equally here too. So if you define a variable as `VALue`, it will rename the `.Value` property wherever it is used.

If you then define a subroutine as `value`, it will rename both the existing `VALue` variable as well as the `.Value` property.

If you follow good naming conventions, and don't reuse names anywhere, then you won't have this issue.

Answer (score 3):

**Naming a variable with the same name as a keyword is not a good practice.**

If a keyword <strike>is used within scope of</strike> [and] a variable <strike>with</strike> [have] the same name, then the keyword must be qualified with the appropriate VBA object model or the variable takes precedence and the keyword will be interpreted by the compiler as that variable.  This results in code that is more error prone and significantly more difficult to maintain.

---

> **"So, my question is what can I do to stop this insane behaviour?"**
>
> *The solution is to not declare a variable with the same name as  a VBA keyword.*

All variables <strike>of equal scope</strike> share the same casing. Changing the case at the declaration changes every instance of the variable <strike>within scope.  Keywords are slightly different, in that they are global but their casing can be changed by a local declaration.</strike>

So in any scope, declaring a variable of the same name as a keyword will cause every instance of that word to share the same casing project wide and the change persists after the declaration is deleted.

---

Keywords are defined by the object model.

*Link with list of keywords in VBA object model (the link in comments goes .NET):*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/keywords-visual-basic-for-applications

*Link to Excel object model (I do not know where to find an condensed list, but if it is an object, property, or method then it is a keyword):*  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel/object-model

---

It can be challenging, and even impossible, to avoid every keyword and this is where scope comes into play and I can offer some easy to follow advice

When you find yourself naming a variable with a potential for conflict  (like row, column, worksheet) etc.

- in all cases, it is better to use a more descriptive name (indexRow, lastRow, rowCounter)
- If you can't come up with something suitable, press F2 to open the object model viewer and search for that name.  Hopefully the search doesn't come up with any results and you can safely use that name.  But if not, look for where the conflict occurs

  - you will not have a problem if you're creating an Excel project and the conflict is found in the Outlook object. You may even consider removing the reference to the Outlook object from your project
  - if it's a property name (like `Color`) or a method (like `Resize`) then you can use with care (in some cases this is actually the ideal, like when assigning properties and methods to your custom classes)
  - if it is an object (like Workbook) then you should not use it.   The risk is too big.

[I struck through the points of scope - it seems I am rather consistent with my naming conventions and was unaware the variables changed case regardless of scope.
Would never have known if not for Michael's answer]

Comment: @Storax Thanks, didn't notice. I'll update link and remove reference to OP.

Comment: I would have absolutely no problem in accepting everything you said if there isn't for one thing - nowhere in the link you sent is `Row` mentioned as a keyword! Nor is `Range`, the object which has `Row` as a property.

Comment: You know what, you're right and I will add to my answer for correction. Thanks you for pointing it out!